# Recognizing computer in masm

Tags: macos, masm

How can I retrieve MAC of network card(s) and what can I retrieve to recognise specific computer and how?

Comment: there should be an API for that... as you can call WINAPI functions in MASM.

Answer (score 0):

Call Win32's [GetAdaptersInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365917%28VS.85%29.aspx)
Just use INVOKE to call it and pass parms.